# Trigger automatic build on dockerhub when some package is updated in official repository

Tags: docker, dockerhub

If I have the automated build set up on DockerHub, for instance, based on `ubuntu:yy_mm` image and in its `Dockerfile` I install some package `foo-bar-ng` through the `apt-get`, **how can I set up the image to be automaticaly rebuilt when the package is updated in Ubuntu repository?**

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only approach I see is to develop and spin up separate private service for myself which will monitor the package version in official Ubuntu repository and trigger the rebuild by "Built triggers" DockerHub feature that is available in automatic build settings:

> Trigger your Automated Build by sending a POST to a specific endpoint.

For instance, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/56372/191688) question about how can new packages be monitored in specific Ubuntu repo.

*(Made this as an answer - let the community vote on it and, especially, provide better answer if there is any)*